# How much PHP and MySQL or MariaDB knowledge should I know to start writing WordPress themes and plug-ins and whatever else a beginner can edit?

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, mysql, rest-api

I'm not a novice web developer. I know how to use Python and Django at a beginner to intermediate level. I know my basic HTML5, CSS, and JS. I've been learning React.js through Scrimba.com as well as CSS Grid and Flexbox.

For PHP do I need to know OOP? I'd like the minimal? I want the minimal possible as I want to focus on Django and Python Data Analysis and then maybe Data Science and the mathematics that go with it.

I just think 1) WordPress is marketable and good to know. 2) I just want WordPress, PHP, and MySQL competency since in the state of Florida it's very in demand 3) I have set up a wordpress site a few months ago. To help with number two.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and as such, questions should be specific to how to **do** something with WordPress.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can get by doing certain things with basic PHP 101, but the more complicated things you want to do, the more you need to know. There's no specific answer to this question, so it's not really a good fit for this site.

Comment: The PHP skills you need are probably more general programming knowledge, learning PHP should have significant carry over to other programming languages as the core concepts are the same, it's just the syntax and the APIs that differ. As for MySQL competency, nope, if you're writing raw SQL queries in WP you've probably done something wrong. Since you know some React, you already know the basic syntax of PHP

Comment: How much PHP competency? I assume the basic variables, if else statements, arrays ( what about a associative arrays?), functions, built-in functions. Now do I need to know PHP object-oriented programming, what about file input output? What else?

Comment: Using this site as a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/  what section should I look at that covers minimal and special features of PHP but that I should also know that's useful for creating themes, plugins and other things that a beginner can mess with in WordPress?